# A function that prints different types' members

Tags: c++, function, templates

I want to write a function that accept many different types,say double and complex. I also want to print their members, say print double value when the type is double , print real and imaginary parts when this type is complex.

if I use template, there will be error, since a double cannot have real and imaginary parts at all.

say

```
template<class T>
void univ_print(T t)
{
if(typeid(T)==typeid(double))
printf("%f\n",t);

else if(typeid(T)==typeid(complex))
printf("%f\t%f\n",t.real, t.imag);


}
```

This doesn't work. So how can I obtain the effect I want.

Thanks!

Comment: You can just overload `univ_print()` for different types instead of using a template. (E.g. have `univ_float(double)` and `univ_float(complex)`.) Templates really only work when you have a bunch of types that can be treated the same, or *mostly* the same, with the differences specialized using traits and/or specific overloads. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: @cdhowie: Good idea, thanks! That's what I want.

Comment: Why on earth are you using `printf`, when `basic_ostream::operator<<` is already defined for most types you would want to display.  Any additional requirements can be handled by specializing `univ_print`.

Comment: You can use either overloading or template specialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template is more useful for cases where types share a interface

```
template<typename T>
T sum(T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Here, we are creating the `sum` function that accepts all types with the interface `operator+`, which includes primitives.

Now, if several types don't share a interface, what you will need to do is to specialize/overload for them. As it happens, overloading a function template is [often superior](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) to specializing.

The (almost standard) way of adding an output function to a custom type is to overload `operator<<` for streams.

```
class Complex
{
    double real, imag;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Complex& c)
    {
        return os << c.real << '\t' << c.imag;
    }
    // public methods...
};
```

And then you can write

```
Complex c;
std::cout << c << std::endl;
```